# my border color doesn't change into black or white?

Tags: html, css

I am implementing a project and when I try to set color white to my
`input border`, it just turns into `gray` instead of `white` ,but its just fine with other colors like red or orange except with black, I have the same issue with black.

code:

```css
.add {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 1.3rem;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: .3rem;
  border-style: solid;
}

.addButton {
  margin-left: 16.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.add input {
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  text-indent: .5rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.add input::placeholder {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<form class="add">
  <input class="addBook" type="text" required maxlength="50" pattern="\S(.*\S)?" title="Your book name can't start or end with white space and should 
     include at least 1 non-white space character" placeholder="e.g Harry Potter" name="" id="">
  <button class="addButton">Add</button>
</form>
```

p.n:[![enter image description here][1]][1]

p.n2[![enter image description here][2]][2]

edit: It was because my browser was in dark mode, in light mode I don't have this issue.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI6PM.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJleM.jpg

Comment: bit confused. You are setting a white border to the `form`, however, you are talking about `input` tag. Please clarify it

Comment: The "placeholder text" is part of the input, but not the input itself. You can change text related style, for example color or font-size, but not the border of the input.

Comment: Do you need the ```input``` and ```button``` borders to be white or black?

Comment: The code you have given doesmnot alter anything if the color is given as e.g. red. Could you expand a bit - show us what does work 'fine' colorwise? Also, have you used your browser's devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied?

Comment: guys there is no difference, I got the same issue still...@Tushar

Comment: white..........@Sunny

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the border in the `.add` class, set the border color in the other  class `.add input`

```css
.add {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 1.3rem;
  /* This is not the input class, this is the entire form. */
  /* Setting the border here will not change the border of your input. */
}

.addButton {
  margin-left: 16.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.add input {
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  border-width: .3rem;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black; /* This is the input class so changing this border will work */
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.add input::placeholder {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

Comment: still the same issue...

Comment: If you give us a screenshot that shows your problem, it would be so much easier to help you as then we would be able to see exactly what you are seeing.

Comment: jus' uploaded the photo to my question, u can check it.

Answer (score 0):

According to this code, We can see the `border-color` property in our code adjust in **form tag** that containing **input tag** and **button tag**.

If we give a `border-color: white;` property to input tag we can identify that border color of input tag changed into white, but **the top and left side borders remain gray**.

[image]
Thru with new Image, I am sorry but I couldn't clearly identify how the hierarchy of HTML elements is set

but I would like to suggest a way like below

1. set `border-style: none;` to input tag
2. wrap input tag with a **div tag**
3. give `'border-color: white;'` to **div tag**

- **div** is a block-level element so it gets bound that its child element

This may be far from what you want, and may not be a recommended method but I hope it will help you a little in the process of finding a solution.

```css
.add {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 1.3rem;
  padding: 1rem;

  border-color: black;
  border-width: .3rem;
  border-style: solid;
    /* We can see border-color property was adjust to .add 'form'
now, We will change input border color */

  background: #00ACC2;
}

.addButton {
  margin-left: 16.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.add .wrapdiv{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: .3rem;
}

.add input {
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  text-indent: .5rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;

  border-style: none;
  background: black;
}

.add input:focus {
  color: white;
}

.add input::placeholder {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<form class="add">
  <div class = "wrapdiv"><input class="addBook" type="text" required maxlength="50" pattern="\S(.*\S)?" title="Your book name can't start or end with white space and should 
     include at least 1 non-white space character" placeholder="e.g Harry Potter" name="" id=""></div>
  <button class="addButton">Add</button>
</form>
```

Take care and have a peaceful Easter day

Comment: didn't work....

Comment: @scorpian111 oh.. I'm sorry
I was wondering if I could get an confirmation for the new answer

Comment: I just updated the result on my post in p.n2 @J4BEZ

Comment: @scorpian111 Well, considering that border-white is applied to different locations, it seems that the code you uploaded and the code applied on the image are slightly different

If you don't mind, can I see the code you put on the image to check the hierarchy of HTML elements?!

Comment: you got any telegram or whatsapp account so I can send you the whole project, cause stackoverflow gives some weird error for editing my code...@J4BEZ

Comment: @scorpian111 Unfortunately, I don't have a Whats app or telegram account.

If you find the code snippets on Stackoverflow a bit tricky to code, I recommend https://jsfiddle.net/ where you can modify them a bit more easily and share your code.

Comment: @scorpian111 If you share your code via 'jsfiddle', it would be easier and you can get better advice from more senior developers who are more experienced.

Comment: never heard of that...thanks for your help @J4BEZ

Comment: @scorpian111 I'm glad it was helpful.
If the code snippet of stackoverflow is still awkward, you could share the code you wrote with jsfiddle so that more people can see it and leave better answers

Comment: @scorpian111 I hope you have a peaceful day and the difficulty of studying the web would be relieved